# How do I wait for a loop to return a value while also running a tkinter mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a window using tkinter and show that window using window.mainloop().

```
window = Tk()
..
..
window.mainloop()
```

This tkinter window has a button that I waiting for the user to press:

```
button = Button(buttonFrame, text='Next', command=pressed)
```

However, I also have physical button in real life that the user can press. I have a function that communicates with the physical button over USB. It just waits in a while loop for the physical button to be pressed and then returns true. So if either the physical or digital button is pressed, the "pressed" function is called.

The problem is I don't know how to wait for both at the same time. The code that waits for the USB response is blocking because it use a while loop. The main loop of tkinter is also blocking. So how can I have both waiting at the same time?

Comment: Look into the `threading` module https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html Basically spawning a thread to watch the physical button for a press would be the route I would go.

Comment: you can try to use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run the same function every few milliseconds without `while` loop and not block `mainloop`. But it can works only if code check button and it return false when it is not pressed - without waiting for press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working using the threading module:

```
window = Tk()
..
..
thread = threading.Thread(target=myButton)
thread.start()
window.mainloop()
```

Inside the myButton function, I call the function to get the button press from the USB button.